# Thread safety - Concurrent hashmap with list as value

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety

I define my map as:

```
Map<String, List<String>> results = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
```

And while adding (which multiple threads will do) I do:

```
  results.putIfAbsent("foo", Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>()));
  results.get("foo").add("bar");
```

Or the java 8 equivalent:

```
results.computeIfAbsent(
    "foo", 
    k -> Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>())
).add("bar");
```

Is what I am doing thread safe?

Answer (score 1):

The code you show doesn't have any obvious threading problems as the collections you are using are thread safe.  Whether your entire program is thread safe depends on the other code in your program.